# Python Processing Multiple If Conditions Inside of a Return Statement

Tags: javascript, return-value, python-3.7, return-type

I am working on translating some code from JavaScript into Python.

In the Javascript I am seeing a lot of processing of multiple conditions inside of a return statement. Here's an example:

```
return '(' +
    Object.entries(query).map((kv) => {
    const key = getCols(kv[0], table)
    if (kv[0] === '$or') {
      return '(' + getQuery(kv[1], table).join(' OR ') + ')'
    } else if (kv[0] === '$null') {
      return format('%s IS NULL', kv[1])
    } else if (kv[0] === '$notnull') {
      return format('%s IS NOT NULL', kv[1])
    } else if (kv[0] === '$not') {
      return 'NOT (' + getQuery(kv[1], table) + ')'
    } else if (kv[0] === '$arrayany') {
      return Object.entries(kv[1])
        .map((x) => {
          return format('%s=ANY(%L)', getCols(x[0], table), value(x[1]))
        })
        .join(' AND ') +
        ')'
```

I haven't seen such complex return statements in Python and am not sure how to build an equivalent statement taking into account all the mappings and joins.
What is a valid Pythonic way to have such deeply nested return statements?

Comment: How do you represent the objects like `query` in python? Are those simple `dict`s?

Comment: In general: `Object.entries(obj) -> obj.items()`, `arr.join(string) -> string.join(arr)`, `arr.map(cb) -> map(cb, arr)` this should solve 90% of the conversion. Assuming you are converting JavaScript objects to python `dict`s. Also: `format(template, val1, val2, ...) -> template.format(val1, val2, ...)` but replace `%<X>` with `{}`.

Comment: Thanks! And regarding the return statements - is it common to have such deeply nested return statements in Python? I can get translate each of the bits on their owns, but combining all of this into a return statement like the Javascript creates a lot of `unreachable code` errors.

Comment: IMHO that code would be more readable split in a couple of functions... The code should look more something like: `return '(' + format_query(query, table)+ ')'` and the `format_query` I would expect it to be something like `' AND '.join(format_query_part(key, value) for key, value in query.items())`, with `format_query_part` that contains the sequence of `if/elif/else`s.

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm going to try to work with this idea.